# What's the correct way to setup different URL prefix in production and development environment?

Tags: angularjs, environment-variables, dev-to-production

How do you setup different URL Prefix in production and development environment? So during development and production there are different domains that are being hit, how do you dynamically switch between two differnt hosts?

This is what I am doing right now.

environment.ts

```
export const environment {
    production: true
}

export const DEVELOPMENT_API_PREFIX = 'http://localhost:55403/api/v1';
export const PRODUCTION_API_PREFIX = 'http://example.com/api/v1';
```

login.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment, PRODUCTION_API_PREFIX, DEVELOPMENT_API_PREFIX } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
  API_PREFIX: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  loginUser(username: string, password: string) {
    if (environment.production) {
      this.API_PREFIX = PRODUCTION_API_PREFIX;
    } else {
      this.API_PREFIX = DEVELOPMENT_API_PREFIX;
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', username);
    formData.append('password', password);
    return this.http.post(this.API_PREFIX + 'login', formData);
  }
}
```

Now the problem with this setup is, that I have to go write an IF statement in a every service. Just wanted to know which is a better way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of most solution is to create **environment.[env].ts** file for each environment. for exemple for production, create **environment.prod.ts** file. So you can use the same key in this new config file. For exemple:

in **environment.prod.ts**

```
API_PREFIX: 'http://xxx'
```

in **environment.ts**

```
API_PREFIX: 'http://xxx
```

Now open your **angular.json** file, find the **configurations** section then process the replacement:

```
"production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
```

then just import the **API_PREFIX**

```
import { environment, API_PREFIX } from '...';
```

You can follow this link for most explanations:
https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/